# BQ Load - how to convert integer seconds into timestamp column

Tags: google-bigquery

When running `bq load` command I set the type of the column to timestamp, but all timestamps are 1970-X-X X:X:X.
I assume it is because BQ takes integer in milliseconds and not seconds.

Is there a solution to load seconds data to timestamp with BQ load command?

Thank you